# Neo4j HA over a VPN?

Tags: networking, ssh, neo4j, vpn, apache-zookeeper

I am currently in the process of creating 3 Neo4j High Availability servers.  My business logic leaves one server as a dedicated master, while the other two machines are dedicated slaves.  My slaves exist in an entirely different datacenter than my master.

What is the best method to establish a link between the two applications?  I've been able to establish connections using OpenVPN, but am curious if that would be better than like SSH port forwarding?  I'm not entirely sure how Zookeeper needs to communicate with each other node.  A VPN connection only creates a one-way connection, where my master, for example, can create a connection with slave, but could not create one with its master. (I think?)

How should I do this?  Thanks!

PS: My master is using an embedded instance of Neo4j, while the slaves are stand-alone instances (if this matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your setup is not about availability as the slaves cannot become masters anyway?

Just about replication to the other datacenter?

You also need to take the neo4j coordinator (zookeeper) into account which is usually needed for all cluster participants.

My colleague suggested that you might get away with just putting the zookeeper (perhaps even just a single one as you don't need master election) directly besides your master server.

Then the ability to connect into the masters' VPN should be enough for the slaves to pull updates.

Comment: That's correct.  Is such a scenario that absurd though?  In this situation, the master continually performs a very resource intensive process based upon streaming data. The slaves merely want to replicate that data and provide availability to other clients.  The clients will be in read-only mode as well.  If there were a way to do this in the community version, such as synchronizing the graph.db/ directory, I'm all ears!
In the meantime, I will try this approach and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: The graph I'm working with has 25+ million nodes, 50+ million relationships, and 60+ million properties, and this build process requires full traversals at the moment to build the data set.

Comment: Community is difficult as you have to shut down the db to take a copy, enterprise also offers hot backups (full and incremental) which result in a fully functioning db-copy.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  I took your advice - though I believe I have found either an error or a bug with this method, but for this issue I posted it on the Neo4j Google Group -> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/neo4j/1cR2i_-kFYo%5B1-25%5D